# Unable to get the Item details from Amazon production API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-product-api

I am using [the gem](https://github.com/abandoned/amazon_product) to get item details.  I am able to get everything except, item description, please suggest how can I get the Item description.Please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/807Gs.png) which I want to get. I have selected the description.

Find my configurations

Gemfile

```
 gem 'amazon_product', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
```

services/amazon_service.rb

```
class AmazonService
    def initialize(params)
        @ItemPage = params[:ItemPage]
        @keyword = params[:keyword]
        @book_id = params[:book_id]
        $req = AmazonProduct['us']
        $req.configure do |c|
        c.key    = ENV['AWS_access_key_id']
        c.secret = ENV['AWS_secret_key']
        c.tag    = ENV['associate_tag']
    end
    end
    def itemlookup`enter code here`
        $req << {
        :operation    => 'ItemLookup',
        :search_index => 'Books',
        :Keywords => 'Book',
        :IdType => 'ISBN',
        :ItemId => @book_id,
        :response_group => ['ItemAttributes','Images'], 
    }
    $req.get
    end
end
```

Controller

```
 @resp = AmazonService.new({book_id: 1338099132}).itemlookup
```

Answer (score 0):

The product description is stored under Editorial Reviews node.

```
EditorialReviews:
    EditorialReview:
      Source: Product Description
      Content: '<ul><li> Front Opening, Long Sleeve, Pure Color, Patternless,
        Draped, Scarf Hem, Stretch, Loose Style, Textured, Ruffled, </li><li>
        The model is about 5.2Ft in height.</li></ul><table border="1" cellpadding="1"
        cellspacing="1" width="200"><tr><td>Asian Size</td><td>International Size</td><td>US
        Size</td><td>Bust Girth</td><td>Waist Girth</td><td>Hip Girth</td><td>Arm
```

To get it need to find Source node with 'Product Description' value

```
product.description = Array.wrap(item.editorial_reviews).
                      find{|er| er['Source'] == 'Product Description'}.
                      try(:fetch, 'Content', nil)
```